# Jquery UI: draggable with constraints?

Tags: jquery, draggable

is it possible to set constraints for a draggable obeject?
I have this line:

```
$("#info").draggable({ axis: 'y' });
```

i want this only to be draggable 200px towards the top. It should not be draggable towards the bottom? Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the demos?
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement

You can use a few of the shown options to achieve what you are looking for (like making a container div that is 200 px higher, etc).